# Melting(unpivot) Pandas dataframe when you have too many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following columns -

```
social_media.columns
Index(['respid', 'sample', 'comp', 'int_date', 'lang', 'cregion', 'state',
       'density', 'sfips', 'usr', 'qs1', 'sex', 'eminuse', 'intmob', 'intfreq',
       'snsint2', 'home4nw', 'bbhome1', 'bbhome2', 'device1a', 'smart2', 'q20',
       'bbsmart1', 'bbsmart2', 'bbsmart3a', 'bbsmart3b', 'bbsmart3c',
       'bbsmart3d', 'bbsmart3e', 'bbsmart3f', 'bbsmart3foe@', 'bbsmart4',
       'web1a', 'web1b', 'web1c', 'web1d', 'web1e', 'web1f', 'web1g', 'web1h',
       'web1i', 'sns2a', 'sns2b', 'sns2c', 'sns2d', 'sns2e', 'device1b',
       'device1c', 'device1d', 'books1', 'books2a', 'books2b', 'books2c',
       'age', 'marital', 'educ2', 'emplnw', 'hisp', 'racem1', 'racem2',
       'racem3', 'racem4', 'racecmb', 'birth_hisp', 'inc', 'party', 'partyln',
       'hh1', 'hh3', 'ql1', 'ql1a', 'qc1', 'weight', 'cellweight'],
      dtype='object')
```

And I want to melt only the columns related to web1a, web1b ---- web1i and want other columns to remain as is it. I know that I have to specify all the columns that I don't want to unpivot, i have to include them in the **id_vars** parameter of the **pandas melt function** but you can see that there are many columns that I have to copy and paste.

Is there any easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with regular expressions to solve your problem for selecting certain columns:

#### Case 1: selecting all columns with `web`:

```
social_media.filter(like='web').columns

Index(['web1a', 'web1b', 'web1c', 'web1d', 'web1e', 'web1f', 'web1g', 'web1h',
       'web1i'],
      dtype='object')
```

#### Case 2: select all columns which do NOT have `web` in the name:

```
social_media.filter(regex='^[^web]').columns

Index(['respid', 'sample', 'comp', 'int_date', 'lang', 'cregion', 'state',
       'density', 'sfips', 'usr', 'qs1', 'sex', 'intmob', 'intfreq', 'snsint2',
       'home4nw', 'device1a', 'smart2', 'q20', 'sns2a', 'sns2b', 'sns2c',
       'sns2d', 'sns2e', 'device1b', 'device1c', 'device1d', 'age', 'marital',
       'hisp', 'racem1', 'racem2', 'racem3', 'racem4', 'racecmb', 'inc',
       'party', 'partyln', 'hh1', 'hh3', 'ql1', 'ql1a', 'qc1', 'cellweight'],
      dtype='object')
```